# What's the name of this catholic chant?

Tags: culture, ceremonies

I attended a ceremony held at the Basilica di Santa Maria Maggiore in Rome on 07/12/2021, and the last chant really impressed me, but I have no clue on how to go to find it.
I tried searching an enormous list of Gregorian chants online, but nothing.

I also cannot understand the words, and so I ran out of ideas on where to go from here...

This is the link to the small segment I recorded: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yuM8OF7bIVDzRSvOum7OkEudP5V0xjn1/view?usp=sharing

Can anyone help me here?
Any ideas where should I look to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no clue on how to go to find it

The main clue is to discern the underlying Latin text.

> I also cannot understand the words

Me either ! But one doesn't have to be a Latin scholar to discern a *spiritus meus* in the lyrics.

> Any ideas where should I look to find it?

The main idea is to get your hands on a searchable Latin bible.

---

Putting these three together, we finally arrive, after a few minutes of brainstorming, to the Vulgate version of:

> <sup>[Luke 1:47-48](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lucas_1:47-48&version=VULGATE)</sup> et exsul*tavit spiritus meus in Deo salutari meo. Quia respexit humilitatem ancillae suae: ecce enim ex hoc bea*tam me dicent omnes generationes.

which is obviously part of the [Magnificat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnificat).

Comment: Perhaps Latin.SE would have been a better fit for this particular type of questions ?

Comment: Personally, I'd love to know what *setting* this is. It isn't any of the several settings with which I'm familiar. (That said, I probably don't want to know how many settings of the Magnificat exist .)